# Variable used in lambda should be final or effectively final for string appending

Tags: java

Java 8

i have a list of objects: myObjs,
each object has a method to get message.
Now i want to append these messages,

```
String myStr = new String();
myObjs.forEach( obj -> {
    myStr = myStr.join(obj->getMessage());
})
```

Q1: how to solve: variable used in lambda should be final or effectively final java
Q2: how to separate each message with comma ?

Comment: The reason for the "variable used in lambda should be final or effectively final" message is an interesting feature of the way lambdas are implemented in Java. Here's an article that explains it: https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-lambas-limitations-closures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple example program

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Test> list = Arrays.asList(new Test(), new Test(), new Test());

        String myStr = list.stream().map(Test::getMessage)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "optional prefix", "optional suffix"));
        System.out.println(myStr); // output = optional prefixmessage,message,messageoptional suffix

    }
}

class Test {
    public String getMessage() {
        return "message";
    }
}
```

*EDIT*
If you have a List of Strings you could also do

```
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
System.out.println(String.join(",", stringList));// a,b,c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a `String` and a lambda (because `String` is immutable, you can't mutate the reference in a lambda), but you can do this with a collector. Like,

```
String myStr = myObjs.stream().map(x -> x.getMessage()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

**or** a `StringBuilder` (but that's messier, and you'd need a check for comma and to manage that joining yourself). I prefer Collectors.joining